# Getting the following errors BCE0048: Type 'UnityEngine.Component' does not support slicing

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have downloaded the model from Asset Store "Cartoon Soldier" and trying to run the game, getting the following error in the code

I have found so many answers and made changes accordingly, seems that nothing fits to my solution. When i make changes to one thing other error comes out.. Finally asking your help please

Error -

```
Assets/Cartoon Soldier/Scripts/soldier/soldierAnimation.js(144,17): BCE0048: Type 'UnityEngine.Component' does not support slicing.

Assets/Cartoon Soldier/Scripts/soldier/soldierAnimation.js(313,34): BCE0138: 'UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent' is not a generic definition.
```

Code for SoldierAnimation.js

```
//Curves.
var idleBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var walkBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var runBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var sprintBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var strafeBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var turnBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var animationSpeedCurve : AnimationCurve;
var turnAnimationSpeedCurve : AnimationCurve;
var fallingBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var landingDurationCurve : AnimationCurve;
var hitBlendCurve : AnimationCurve;
var tiltMultiplier : float = 1.0;

//Animation blend values.
var idleBlend : float;
var walkBlend : float;
var runBlend : float;
var sprintBlend : float;
var strafeBlend : float;
var turnBlend : float;
var animationSpeed : float;
var turnAnimationSpeed : float;
var fallingBlend : float;
var landingDuration : float;
var landingInhibit : float;
var landingBlend : float;
var crouchIdleBlend : float;
var crouchRunBlend : float;
var crouchSprintBlend : float;
var crouchStrafeBlend : float;
var crouchTurnBlend : float;
var hitBlend : float;
var dieBlend : float;
//---
private var soldierRotation : Quaternion;
private var verticalSpeed : float;
private var lastPosition : Vector3;
private var lastYRotation : float;
private var tilt : float;
private var backward : boolean; //Switch when strafing backwards.
private var backwardBuffer : float = 0.5; //So it doesn switches too fast.
private var lastLandingTime : float; //Last time soldier landed after a fall.
private var isFalling : boolean;
private var startedFallingTime : float;
private var isGrounded : boolean;
private var hitStartTime : float; //Time in which hit animation should start playing.
private var getHitDirection : Vector3;
//External scripts.
private var crouchControllerScript : crouchController;
private var weaponControllerScript : weaponController;
private var healthScript : health;
//
function Start(){
    soldierRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    globalCrouchBlend = 0.0;
    globalCrouchBlendTarget = 0.0;
    globalCrouchBlendVelocity = 0.0;
    crouchControllerScript = transform.root.GetComponent(crouchController);
    weaponControllerScript = transform.root.GetComponent(weaponController);
    healthScript = transform.root.GetComponent(health);
}

function LateUpdate(){
    //Gather external script info.
    var firing : boolean = false; //Firing.
    if (weaponControllerScript != null){
         firing = weaponControllerScript.isFiring();
    }
    var crouchInhibit : float = 1.0;//Crouch.
    var standInhibit : float = 0.0;
    var crouchSpeedMultiplier : float = 1.0;
    if(crouchControllerScript != null){
        crouchInhibit = 1 - crouchControllerScript.globalCrouchBlend;
        standInhibit = (1 -crouchInhibit);
        crouchSpeedMultiplier = crouchControllerScript.crouchSpeedMultiplier;
    }
    var lastHitTime : float;
    var hitDirection : Vector3;
    var health : float;
    var deathTime : float;
    if (healthScript != null){
        lastHitTime = healthScript.GetLastHitTime();
        hitDirection = healthScript.GetHitDirection();
        health = healthScript.health;
        deathTime = healthScript.GetDeathTime();
    }
    //Velocity calculation.
    var velocity : Vector3 = (transform.position - lastPosition) / Time.deltaTime; //Units per second.
    var previousVerticalSpeed : float = verticalSpeed;
    verticalSpeed = (transform.position.y - lastPosition.y) / Time.deltaTime;
    var overallSpeed : float = (transform.position - lastPosition).magnitude / Time.deltaTime;
    lastPosition = transform.position;
    var forwardSpeed : float = transform.InverseTransformDirection(velocity).z;
    var strafeSpeed : float = transform.InverseTransformDirection(velocity).x;
    var turnSpeed : float = Mathf.DeltaAngle(lastYRotation, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y);
    lastYRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    //Is grounded.
    var rayHeight : float = 0.3;
    var rayOrigin : Vector3 = transform.position + Vector3.up * rayHeight;
    var groundRay : Ray = new Ray(rayOrigin, Vector3.down);
    var rayDistance : float = rayHeight * 2.0;
    var groundHit : RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(groundRay, groundHit, rayDistance)){
        isGrounded = true;
    }
    else{
        isGrounded = false;
    }
    //Animation blending.
    minimumFallSpeed  = -0.5; //Should be called maximum.
    if (!isFalling && verticalSpeed < minimumFallSpeed && !isGrounded){ //Start falling time.
        isFalling = true;
        startedFallingTime = Time.time;
    }
    var totalFallDuration : float = 0.0;
    if(isFalling && verticalSpeed > minimumFallSpeed){ //Land time.
        isFalling = false;
        lastLandingTime = Time.time;
        totalFallDuration = (lastLandingTime - startedFallingTime);
        landingDuration = landingDurationCurve.Evaluate(totalFallDuration);
    }
    var fallDuration : float;
    if (Time.time > startedFallingTime && isFalling){//Current fall duration.
        fallDuration = Time.time - startedFallingTime;
    }
    else{
        fallDuration = 0.0;
    }
    //Animation blending values.
    var hitInhibit : float = 1 - hitBlend;//Make other animations inhibit when getting hit.
    var dieInhibit : float = 1 - dieBlend;//Don't play animations if dying.
    var blendSpeed : float = 0.2;
    fallingBlend = fallingBlendCurve.Evaluate(fallDuration); //Falling blend.
    fallingBlend *= dieInhibit;
    animation.Blend("soldierFalling",fallingBlend,blendSpeed);
    var fallingInhibit : float = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(1 - fallingBlend),2.0);//Make other animations inhibit when falling.
    if(Time.time < lastLandingTime + landingDuration){ //Landing blend.
        var timeSinceLanding : float =  Time.time - lastLandingTime;
        var landingProgress : float = timeSinceLanding / landingDuration; //From 0 to 1.
        landingProgress = Mathf.Pow(landingProgress, 0.6);
        landingBlend = 1 - landingProgress;
        var landingAnimationStartTime : float = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - landingDuration);
        animation["soldierLanding"].time = Mathf.Lerp(landingAnimationStartTime, 1.0 ,landingProgress);
        animation.Blend("soldierLanding",landingBlend,0.05);
        landingInhibit = Mathf.Pow(1 - landingBlend,2.0);
    }
    else{
        landingBlend = 0.0;
        landingDuration = 0.0;
        landingAnimationStartTime = 0.0;
        landingInhibit = 1.0;
    }
    var idleBlend = idleBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(forwardSpeed) + Mathf.Abs(strafeSpeed)); //Idle blend.
    idleBlend -= Mathf.Abs(turnSpeed) * .8;
    idleBlend *= fallingInhibit;
    idleBlend *= landingInhibit;
    idleBlend *= crouchInhibit;
    idleBlend *= hitInhibit;
    idleBlend *= dieInhibit;
    //idleBlend = Mathf.Clamp01(idleBlend);
    animation.Blend("soldierIdle",idleBlend,blendSpeed);
    walkBlend = walkBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(forwardSpeed)); //Walk blend.
    walkBlend *= fallingInhibit;
    walkBlend *= landingInhibit;
    walkBlend *= crouchInhibit;
    walkBlend *= dieInhibit;
    walkBlend = Mathf.Clamp01(walkBlend);
    animation.Blend("soldierWalk",walkBlend,blendSpeed);
    runBlend = runBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(forwardSpeed)); //Run blend.
    runBlend *= fallingInhibit;
    runBlend *= landingInhibit;
    runBlend  *= crouchInhibit;
    runBlend *= dieInhibit;
    //runBlend = Mathf.Clamp01(runBlend);
    animation.Blend("soldierRun",runBlend,blendSpeed);
    sprintBlend = sprintBlendCurve.Evaluate(forwardSpeed);//Sprint blend.
    sprintBlend *= fallingInhibit;
    sprintBlend *= landingInhibit;
    sprintBlend *= crouchInhibit;
    sprintBlend *= dieInhibit;
    //sprintBlend = Mathf.Clamp01(sprintBlend);
    animation.Blend("soldierSprint",sprintBlend,blendSpeed);
    strafeBlend = strafeBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(strafeSpeed)); //Strafing blend.
    strafeBlend *= fallingInhibit;
    strafeBlend *= landingInhibit;
    strafeBlend *= crouchInhibit;
    strafeBlend *= dieInhibit;
    //strafeBlend = Mathf.Clamp01(strafeBlend);
    if (forwardSpeed > backwardBuffer){
        backward = false;
    }
    if(forwardSpeed < -backwardBuffer){
        backward = true;
    }
    if(!backward){
        if(strafeSpeed > 0){
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeRight",strafeBlend,blendSpeed);
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeLeft",0,blendSpeed);
        }
        else{
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeLeft",strafeBlend,blendSpeed);
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeRight",0,blendSpeed);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(strafeSpeed > 0){
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeLeft",strafeBlend,blendSpeed);
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeRight",0,blendSpeed);
        }
        else{
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeRight",strafeBlend,blendSpeed);
            animation.Blend("soldierStrafeLeft",0,blendSpeed);
        }   
    }
    turnBlend = turnBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(turnSpeed)); //Turn blend.
    turnBlend -= overallSpeed;
    turnBlend = Mathf.Clamp01(turnBlend);
    turnBlend *= crouchInhibit;
    turnBlend *= dieInhibit;
    if(turnSpeed > 0){
        animation.Blend("soldierSpinRight",turnBlend,blendSpeed);
        animation.Blend("soldierSpinLeft",0,blendSpeed);
    }
    else{
        animation.Blend("soldierSpinLeft",turnBlend,blendSpeed);
        animation.Blend("soldierSpinRight",0,blendSpeed);   
    }
    //Crouch Idle animation blending. Blend values are calculated above for convenince.
    if (crouchControllerScript != null){ //Works with a global crouch value that's handled in the crouch controller script. 
        var inverseCrouchSpeedMultiplier : float = (1/crouchSpeedMultiplier);
        crouchIdleBlend = idleBlendCurve.Evaluate((Mathf.Abs(forwardSpeed) + Mathf.Abs(strafeSpeed))* inverseCrouchSpeedMultiplier); //Crouch idle blend.
        crouchIdleBlend -= Mathf.Abs(turnSpeed) * .8;
        crouchIdleBlend *= fallingInhibit;
        crouchIdleBlend *= landingInhibit;
        crouchIdleBlend *= standInhibit;
        crouchIdleBlend *= dieInhibit;
        animation.Blend("soldierCrouch",crouchIdleBlend,0.05);
        crouchRunBlend = runBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(forwardSpeed) * inverseCrouchSpeedMultiplier);//Crouch run blend.
        crouchRunBlend *= fallingInhibit;
        crouchRunBlend *= landingInhibit;
        crouchRunBlend *= standInhibit;
        crouchRunBlend *= dieInhibit;
        animation.Blend("soldierCrouchRun",crouchRunBlend,0.05);
        crouchSprintBlend = sprintBlendCurve.Evaluate(forwardSpeed * inverseCrouchSpeedMultiplier);//Crouch sprint blend.
        crouchSprintBlend *= fallingInhibit;
        crouchSprintBlend *= landingInhibit;
        crouchSprintBlend *= standInhibit;
        crouchSprintBlend *= dieInhibit;
        animation.Blend("soldierCrouchSprint",crouchSprintBlend,0.05);
        crouchStrafeBlend = strafeBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(strafeSpeed) * inverseCrouchSpeedMultiplier); //Crouch strafe blend.
        crouchStrafeBlend *= fallingInhibit;
        crouchStrafeBlend *= landingInhibit; 
        crouchStrafeBlend *= standInhibit;
        crouchStrafeBlend *= dieInhibit;
        if(!backward){
            if(strafeSpeed > 0){
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeRight",crouchStrafeBlend,blendSpeed*2);
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeLeft",0,blendSpeed*2);
            }
            else{
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeLeft",crouchStrafeBlend,blendSpeed*2);
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeRight",0,blendSpeed*2);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(strafeSpeed > 0){
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeLeft",crouchStrafeBlend,blendSpeed*2);
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeRight",0,blendSpeed*2);         
            }
            else{
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeRight",crouchStrafeBlend,blendSpeed*2);
                animation.Blend("soldierCrouchStrafeLeft",0,blendSpeed*2);          
            }
        }
        crouchTurnBlend = turnBlendCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(turnSpeed)); //Crouch turn blend.
        crouchTurnBlend -= overallSpeed;
        crouchTurnBlend = Mathf.Clamp01(crouchTurnBlend);
        crouchTurnBlend *= standInhibit;
        crouchTurnBlend *= dieInhibit;
        if(turnSpeed > 0){
            animation.Blend("soldierCrouchSpinRight", crouchTurnBlend, blendSpeed);
            animation.Blend("soldierCrouchSpinLeft",0, blendSpeed);
        }
        else{
            animation.Blend("soldierCrouchSpinLeft", crouchTurnBlend, blendSpeed);
            animation.Blend("soldierCrouchSpinRight",0, blendSpeed);            
        }       
    }
    var timeAfterHit : float = Time.time - lastHitTime; //Hit blend.
    getHitBlend = hitBlendCurve.Evaluate(timeAfterHit);
    hitBlend = getHitBlend;
    hitBlend *= dieInhibit;
    var frontHitBlend : float = hitBlend * Mathf.Max(hitDirection.z,0);
    animation.Blend("soldierHitFront",frontHitBlend,blendSpeed);
    var backHitBlend : float = hitBlend * -Mathf.Min(hitDirection.z,0);
    animation.Blend("soldierHitBack",backHitBlend,blendSpeed);
    var rightHitBlend : float = hitBlend * Mathf.Max(hitDirection.x,0);
    animation.Blend("soldierHitRight",rightHitBlend,blendSpeed);
    var leftHitBlend : float = hitBlend * -Mathf.Min(hitDirection.x,0);
    animation.Blend("soldierHitLeft",leftHitBlend,blendSpeed);
    var timeSinceDeath : float = Time.time - deathTime;
    var dying : boolean = false;
    if(timeSinceDeath > 0.1){
        dying = true;
    }
    if(!dying){
        getHitDirection = hitDirection;
    }
    if (health <= 0){  //Die blend.
        dieBlend = 1.0;
        if (getHitDirection.z > 0){
            GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieFront"].time = timeSinceDeath;
            if(GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieFront"].time > GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieFront"].length){
                GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieFront"].time = GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieFront"].length;
            }
            GetComponent.<Animation>.Blend("soldierDieFront",dieBlend,blendSpeed);
        }
        else{
            GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieBack"].time = timeSinceDeath;
            if(GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieBack"].time > GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieBack"].length){
                GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieBack"].time = GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierDieBack"].length;
            }
            GetComponent.<Animation>.Blend("soldierDieBack",dieBlend,blendSpeed);
        }
    }
    else{
        dieBlend = 0.0;
    }
    //Animation speed.
    var animationSpeed : float;
    var strafeSpeedMultiplier : float = 1.4; //Speed up strafe animations.

    if(!backward){
        animationSpeed = animationSpeedCurve.Evaluate(overallSpeed);
    }
    else{
        animationSpeed = -animationSpeedCurve.Evaluate(overallSpeed);
    }
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierWalk"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierRun"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierSprint"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierStrafeRight"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierStrafeLeft"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierCrouchRun"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierCrouchSprint"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierCrouchStrafeRight"].speed = animationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierCrouchStrafeLeft"].speed = animationSpeed;
    var turnAnimationSpeed : float = turnAnimationSpeedCurve.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(turnSpeed));
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierSpinRight"].speed = turnAnimationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierSpinLeft"].speed = turnAnimationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierCrouchSpinRight"].speed = turnAnimationSpeed;
    GetComponent.<Animation>["soldierCrouchSpinLeft"].speed = turnAnimationSpeed;
    //Torso recoil when firing.
    if (firing){
        var spine1 = transform.Find("Bip01/Bip01 Pelvis/Bip01 Spine/Bip01 Spine1");
        var spine2 = spine1.Find("Bip01 Spine2");
        spine1.localRotation.eulerAngles.z += Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 50) * 0.5;
        spine2.localRotation.eulerAngles.z += Mathf.Sin(Time.time * 50 - 1.0) * 0.5;
    }
    //Rotation.
    var deltaAngle : float = Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, transform.root.rotation.eulerAngles.y);
    var turnAngle : float = Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(deltaAngle), 2.5) * Mathf.Sign(deltaAngle) / 80;
    turnAngle *= dieInhibit;
    soldierRotation.eulerAngles.y += turnAngle * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.rotation = soldierRotation;
    //Tilt
    var tiltTarget = -turnAngle * 0.01 * forwardSpeed * tiltMultiplier;
    Mathf.Clamp(tiltTarget,-30,30);
    tilt = Mathf.Lerp(tilt, tiltTarget, Time.deltaTime * 7.0);
    if (Mathf.Abs(verticalSpeed) > 1){
        tilt /= Mathf.Abs(verticalSpeed);
    }
    transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z = tilt;
}
```

I tried changing the animation to GetComponent.  or GetComponent(animation), error gets changed ?? any final solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First error***:

For example:

Replace

```
 (animation as Animation)["run"] as AnimationClip).normalizedSpeed = runSpeedScale;
```

To

```
 ((GetComponent.<Animation>() as Animation)["run"] as AnimationClip).normalizedSpeed = runSpeedScale;
```

Or

```
GetComponent.<Animation>()["run"].normalizedSpeed = runSpeedScale;
```

***Second error***:

On `GetComponent`. Change it to `GetComponent.();`.

For example:

Replace

```
 defaultPlayer.GetComponent.<NetworkView>.RPC("PlayerOne",RPCMode.Others);
```

To

```
defaultPlayer.GetComponent.<NetworkView>().RPC("PlayerOne",RPCMode.Others);
```

This may solve your errors.